# How do I change schema.xml without restarting Solr?

Tags: solr

I've added `"copyField source="product" dest="text"/"` in **schema.xml**

**solrconfig.xml**

```xml
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
       will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    <int name="rows">10</int>
    <str name="df">text</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I restarted solr and loaded the data again to reflect changes made. My question is whether it is necessary to restart solr every time I make a change in schema.xml.

Answer (score 15):

You can issue a RELOAD command to the core -

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0
```

That would let you avoid restarting tomcat or jetty and avoid most of the downtime as it will keep the old core running until the new core is ready.

However there are a few things configuration wise that would require a restart. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3592 and https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD

Comment: As of Solr 6.4 a schema change doesn't require a server restart. It maybe true for Solr 6.x in general but I verified on Solr 6.4 only.

Comment: @PrashantSaraswat That's only valid for the ManagedSchema - the classic schema factory will still require a manual reload of the core.